# Extending a method with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I created a `FileHandler` class with methods to read a file or many files like this.

```
export class FileHandler {
    private static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
        const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
        const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
        return { path, encoding, flag, content };
    }
    static async readFile (a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File> {
        if (typeof a === 'string') a = FileQueryHandler.getFromPath(a, b);
        return FileHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(a);
    }
    static async readFiles (a: (Path | FileQuery)[] | Directory, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {        
        if (a instanceof Array) return Promise.all(a.map(p => this.readFile(p, b)));
        return FileHandler.readFiles(PathHandler.getFromDirectory(a), b);
    }
    static async readFilesFromDirectory(a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {
        const ps = await DirectoryHandler.readDirectory(a);    
        if (typeof a === 'string') return await FileHandler.readFiles(ps, b);
        return await FileHandler.readFiles(ps, a);
    }
}
```

This is a class with `static` methods because I don't need them to be public.

What I would like to do now is expand upon this class.

I would like to wrap the `FileHandler.readFile` in a try catch and possibly return null, something like this, where the method is named `readFile` but the return value is different from the original.

```
export class FileOrNullHandler {
    async readFile (a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File | null> {
        return orNull(() => FileHandler.readFile(a, b));
    }
}
```

I would also like to get all the other methods for free because what I see is all the original `FileHandler` are based on `FileHandler.readFile`.

I've tried some ways of converting both to not use `static` methods, and I've also experimented with return types, but nothing is jumping out at me as the simple way to do this.

What I need is the following:

- Have parity between methods within both classes
- Have all the return values represent the class functionality

I am looking for the best way to do this.

Ideally, the first thing that comes to mind would be I would be able to use

- `static` methods that call `this`
- `ReturnType<this.method>`

But both of those things do not exist.

What I want is the following result:

- `FileHandler.readFile` that returns `File | null`
- `FileHandler.readFiles` that returns `File[]`
- `FileHandler.readFilesFromDirectory` that returns `File[]`
- `FileOrNullHandler.readFile` that returns `(File | null)`
- `FileOrNullHandler.readFiles` that returns `(File | null)[]`
- `FileOrNullHandler.readFilesFromDirectory` that returns `(File | null)[]`

Comment: You should not use a `class` at all. Classes are meant to create instances, not to be used as a collection of static "methods". You are looking for TypeScript namespaces or JavaScript object literals.

Comment: @Bergi sure, can you please show how you'd expand on a method set using another syntax?

Comment: Using `this` to refer to the methods looks good, you could then *extend* your `FileHandler` object, using either inheritance with `Object.create` or a copy with `Object.assign`, and then overwrite the `readFile` function. I have no idea how to type this properly in TypeScript though, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: Interesting, i have few notes:

Why did you need to extend some methods only to change its return type ?
If as you mentioned you only need to return file | null, you can do it using typescript.
Also if you need to extend some functionality you should add it to a super class and extends that class. So you can also override the base class method.
Finally, using static methods inside normal class does not make sense for me. I suggest you to add utilities which should be static classes or namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it makes little sense to have a class just with static properties, thats just a very complicated way to build up an object:

```
export const FileHandler = {
   readFile (a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File> {
     // ...
   }
};
```

The  you can create the wrapper as:

```
 const FileOrNullHandler = Object.assign(...Object.keys(FileHandler).map(key => ({
   [key]: function(...args) {
     return orNull(() => FileHandler[key](...args);
   }
 })));
```

Comment: How would the methods imported over to `FileOrNullHandler` know to now use the 'local' `ReadFile` method?

Answer (score 0):

I found this way of achieving this functionality that maintains static classes, but the types aren't properly represented in `FileOrNullHandler`.

```
export function sibling (v) {
    const staticClassName = v.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1];
    const m = {
        FileHandler,
        FileOrNullHandler
    }
    return m[staticClassName];
}

export class FileHandler {
    static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
        const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
        const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
        return { path, encoding, flag, content };
    }
    static async readFile (a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File> {
        if (typeof a === 'string') a = FileQueryHandler.getFromPath(a, b);
        return sibling(this).readFileFromFileQuery(a);
    }
    static async readFiles (a: (Path | FileQuery)[] | Directory, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {        
        if (a instanceof Array) return Promise.all(a.map(p => sibling(this).readFile(p, b)));
        return sibling(this).readFiles(PathHandler.getFromDirectory(a), b);
    }
    static async readFilesFromDirectory(a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {
        const ps = await DirectoryHandler.readDirectory(a);    
        if (typeof a === 'string') return await sibling(this).readFiles(ps, b);
        return await sibling(this).readFiles(ps, a);
    }
}

export class FileOrNullHandler {
    static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File | null> {
        return orNull(() => FileHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(fq));
    }
    static readFile = FileHandler.readFile;
    static readFiles = FileHandler.readFiles;
    static readFilesFromDirectory = FileHandler.readFilesFromDirectory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that static class methods can use `this`, and extend. However the types are still not accurate.

```
export class FileHandler {
    static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
        const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
        const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
        return { path, encoding, flag, content };
    }
    static async readFile (a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File> {
        if (typeof a === 'string') a = FileQueryHandler.getFromPath(a, b);
        return this.readFileFromFileQuery(a);
    }
    static async readFiles (a: (Path | FileQuery)[] | Directory, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {        
        if (a instanceof Array) return Promise.all(a.map(p => this.readFile(p, b)));
        return this.readFiles(PathHandler.getFromDirectory(a), b);
    }
    static async readFilesFromDirectory(a: Path | FileQuery, b?: Omit<FileQuery, 'path'>): Promise<File[]> {
        const ps = await DirectoryHandler.readDirectory(a);    
        if (typeof a === 'string') return await this.readFiles(ps, b);
        return await this.readFiles(ps, a);
    }
}

export class FileOrNullHandler extends FileHandler {
    static async readFileFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File | null> {
        return orNull(() => FileHandler.readFileFromFileQuery(fq));
    }
}
```